# AnkhSVN - can't add project to subversion

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

Is anyone here familiar with ankhsvn?

I have a solution with several projects (3 C# and 2 C++), but when right-clicking on a project, I only get the option to add the solution to subversion. The option to add just the project is grayed out. Anyone know how to do this? What can be the problem?

Answer (score -2):

You must first create a Subversion repository from outside
the Visual Studio environment.

You can do this using a Subversion client such as TortoiseSVN, or the command "svnadmin create
`<repository_path>` at the Subversion command line.

from [ankhsvn get start page](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_getting_started.html)

Comment: I have a SVN repository. I can add the whole solution to it. Only the option to add a specific project is grayed out in the menu. This is before I even get as far as entering the repo URL. Please read the question.